# Как сделать итоговую строку в PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

Я создаю файл при помощи PHPExcel

```
Дата              | Номер | Цена
01.10.2014 0:32   |   1   |  200
12.09.2013 12:22  |   2   |  300
23.11.2014 15:12  |   3   |  200
Итог:             |       |  700
```

В шапку добавляю автофильтры:

```
$active_sheet->setAutoFilter('A8:E8');
```

Но в фильтре можно выбрать так же итоговую строку (если делать таблицу в EXcel - это невозможно), к тому же при фильтрации (если итоги не скрывать) идет неправильный подсчет, учитываются все строки, даже те, которые мы отфильтровали

Comment: А этоговая строка находиться в диапазоне фильтра?

Comment: В том то и дело, что непонятно, как указать этот диапазон, по умолчанию он забирает все строки, которые идут ниже. По идее должен быть специальный инструмент для создания итоговой строки, сейчас если выбрать фильтр по цене, и не фильтровать итоговую строку, подсчет в ней все равно идет не правильно (т.е. строки, которые отфильтровались - все равно учитываются

Comment: Если у Вас значение цены в одной и той же строке, то можете добавить переменную, которая будет считать сумму с Ваших значений. А потом - вывести его.

Comment: Нужно чтобы в пользователь в самом файле смог отфильтровать значения, и получить результат в итоговой строке. Вот тут написал подробнее: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/455156/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-phpexcel