# Как правильно оформить итоговую строку в PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

Допустим нам нужна такая табличка:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mN0i.jpg

Дополнительно нужны фильтры в шапке, делаю все так:

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

```
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    $active_sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

    $active_sheet->setCellValue('A3', '№');
    $active_sheet->setCellValue('B3', 'Товар');
    $active_sheet->setCellValue('C3', 'Цена');

    $active_sheet->setAutoFilter('A3:C3');

    $active_sheet->setCellValue('A4', '1');
    $active_sheet->setCellValue('B4', 'Товар 1');
    $active_sheet->setCellValue('C4', '200');

    $active_sheet->setCellValue('A5', '2');
    $active_sheet->setCellValue('B5', 'Товар 2');
    $active_sheet->setCellValue('C5', '500');

    $active_sheet->setCellValue('A6', '3');
    $active_sheet->setCellValue('B6', 'Товар 3');
    $active_sheet->setCellValue('C6', '120');

    $active_sheet->setCellValue('A7', '4');
    $active_sheet->setCellValue('B7', 'Товар 4');
    $active_sheet->setCellValue('C7', '245');

    $active_sheet->setCellValue('A8', '5');
    $active_sheet->setCellValue('B8', 'Товар 5');
    $active_sheet->setCellValue('C8', '130');

    $active_sheet->setCellValue('A9', 'Итог');
    $active_sheet->setCellValue('C9', '=SUM(C4:C8)');

    header("Content-Type:application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=simple.xls");

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');

    exit();
```

Получаем таблицу:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5zod.jpg

Все бы хорошо, но при выборе фильтра:

i.stack.imgur.com/go3G6.png

Итоговая строка тоже попадает под фильтрацию, а если применить фильтр по цене например, сумма в итоговой строке не меняется..

Как правильно реализовать табличку с фильтрами и строкой итогов?

Comment: С пересчетом итогов фильтрация не справится. Сделайте веб-приложение с фильтрацией, и пересчетом. У вас же php в руках. А свой ответ я удалю

Comment: Но ведь в обычном Excel это можно сделать..

Comment: Точно. Используйте `SUBTOTAL` вместо `SUM` и будет считать только отфильтрованные

Comment: Спасибо большое! Попробовал сделать вручную - работает, а вот при генерации с PHPExcel: $active_sheet->setCellValue('C9', '=SUBTOTAL(9;C4:C8)');, или так $active_sheet->setCellValue('C9', '=SUBTOTAL(109;C4:C8)'); файл не генерируется, при попытке отдать на скачивание происходит ошибка: "Файл не найден", если убрать эту строчку - все ок, не подскажете в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Посмотрите на предмет ошибок в логах

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все-таки восстановлю ответ в связи с новыми обстоятельствами.

Боюсь это ограничение Excel и Calc. Попробуйте вынести итог выше фильтра (в смысле это получится, но допустимо-ли это в вашем случае - не знаю).
Также дополню информацией из комментария: "Чтобы считались только отфильтрованные значения, нужно использовать функцию `SUBTOTAL()` вместо `SUM()`".

Однако посмотрим на исходники PHPExcel:

```
    'SUBTOTAL' => array(
        'category' => PHPExcel_Calculation_Function::CATEGORY_MATH_AND_TRIG,
        'functionCall' => 'PHPExcel_Calculation_MathTrig::SUBTOTAL',
        'argumentCount' => '2+'
    ),
    'SUM' => array(
        'category' => PHPExcel_Calculation_Function::CATEGORY_MATH_AND_TRIG,
        'functionCall' => 'PHPExcel_Calculation_MathTrig::SUM',
        'argumentCount' => '1+'
    ),
```

Особенно интересует строка `'argumentCount' => '2+'`. (я сам был удивлен, когда узнал). Первым аргументом нужно указать как считать итог (для суммы с игнорированием скрытых значений должно стоять <del>109</del> **9**). Подробнее в [документации](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBTOTAL-function-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939) (прошу прощения, что на английском, но по русски многие функции выглядят ужасно)

Comment: В том, что нужно передавать номер функции, нету ничего особенного, в самом Excel тоже так. Я пробовал выполнить: $active_sheet->setCellValue('C9', '=SUBTOTAL(109;C4:C8)');, но при попытке отдать файл на скачивание - он не генерируется, а если попробовать генерацию в формат Excel2007 происходит такая ошибка: http://savepic.ru/7940447.jpg, а ячейка C9 содержит цифру "0"

Comment: Копнул глубже: а) 109 - не поддерживается PHPExcel (нужно использовать 9); б) в функциях внутри PHPExcel разделителем аргументов является запятая

Comment: Сработало, большое спасибо за помощь! :)

Comment: > б) в функциях внутри PHPExcel разделителем аргументов является запятая - о, спасибо, а я мучался )